# Повторное открытие дочернего окна с сохранением старых данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал родительское окно и дочернее, в родительском окне по нажатию клавиши открывается дочернее окно в нем есть поля ввода и кнопка сохранения, после нажатие кнопки сохранить ,хочу чтобы после повторного вызова дочернего окна поля ввода не стирались, не могу понять. Вот фрагмент функции вызова дочернего окна

```
def child():
    def save():
        window.withdraw()
        btn_1['state'] = 'active'
    window = Toplevel()
    window.geometry('730x280')
    btn_save = Button(window, text = "save",command=save)
    btn_save .place(x=10,y=10)
    text = Text(window)
    text.place(x=10,y=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сразу после создания окна его скрывать (`window.withdraw()`), потом при необходимости показать окно - отображать его (`child_window.deiconify()`), а не создавать новый объект окна:

```
from tkinter import *


def child():
    def save():
        window.withdraw()
        # btn_1['state'] = 'active'
    
    window = Toplevel()
    window.withdraw()  # <- сразу скрыть окно после создания
    
    window.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window.withdraw)  # <- при закрытии окна через крестик скрывать его
    
    window.geometry('730x280')
    btn_save = Button(window, text = "save",command=save)
    btn_save.pack()
    text = Text(window)
    text.pack()
    
    return window  # <- вернуть объект окна из функции


root = Tk()

child_window = child()  # Сразу создается объект окна, но сначала не отображается

Button(
    root,
    text="Show window",
    command=child_window.deiconify  # <- при нажатии на кнопку отобразить окно
).pack()

root.mainloop()
```